# Process killed with -9 aborts?

Tags: linux, coredump

I'm sending SIG_KILL to process on Linux, during the exit it encounters a memory bug and aborts generating core dump. I don't think it is possible on any Unix system, however this is what I observe. Is it possible for process killed by signal 9 to die from any other signal and to leave a core dump?

Answer (score 0):

No, process can't catch SIGKILL but there is an option for a "process watcher" or wrapper.
Are you sure that not other processes are spawned to watch this process?

Comment: I don't say the SIGKILL was caught, what I observed, the signal was sent to process and process died living core dump!!! looking at the core, the process aborted after uncaught exception was thrown during data clean-up. Unless this is coincidence... The process was started from crontab. What are these "process watchers" and how can they affect the way process dies? I've never heard about that.